# ejabberd server issue on linux mint

Tags: linux, ejabberd

I have rencently installed ejabberd server on my linux mint 18. installation finished successfully, but the problem is that i can't access web-console from browser (localhost:5280), when i check status in terminal everything seems fine. i also readed logs and there weren't any suspicious records. even more.. i connect chat.localhost from pidgin client and created 2 users.

please help me to solve this issue how can i enter to web-console from browser

status:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPWiv.png]

Answer (score 0):

please run `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 5280` to check if ejabberd is binding to the port.

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::5280                 :::*                    LISTEN      11916/beam.smp

Comment: seems fine. can you try http://127.0.0.1:5280/admin/ ? If it still does not work, did you enable the web interface in the config? See also https://www.ejabberd.im/files/doc/guide.html#htoc20

Comment: port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
    "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
    "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    register: true
    captcha: true
    tls: true
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"

Comment: in config.cfg everything seems fine, but i cant' access web-admin

Comment: config.cfg  was depricated. i made changes in config.yml but result was same